# Removing duplicates from one filed where the rest of the row isn't duplicated

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem where the data set is sometimes returning 2 rows for a serial number. This occurs when a serial number has been removed and has one row where the removal date is NULL and one where its populated

I've managed to get a query where the NULLS are removed by using a min() and group by clause but this is also removing the NULLs where the meter hasn't been removed.

```
SELECT  [MeterSerialNumber]
      ,[EquipmentType]
      ,[InstallDate]
      ,min ([Removaldate] ) as REM_DATE
      ,round (DATEDIFF(DAY,InstallDate,case when Removaldate IS null then convert (date,GETDATE()) else Removaldate end)/30.42,0) as Age_M


  FROM [DOCDPT].[main].[Tbl_Device_ISU]

  where EquipmentType in ('S1','NS','NSS') or EquipmentType like ('%S2%')


  Group by MeterSerialNumber,EquipmentType,InstallDate,Removaldate having COUNT(distinct removaldate) =1

order by MeterSerialNumber
  ,Removaldate desc
```

These are the results prior to adding in the min() and group by clause. I would like to remove row 2 as the meter has been removed but leave the bottom 2 rows. The code above seems to just remove all the NULLS. I only want to remove the NULLs where the meterserialnumber appears more than once.

```
MeterSerialNumber I EquipmentType I InstallDate I  Removaldate  I Age_M
000009501794462   I S1            I 2017-06-18  I  2018-01-22   I  7.000000
000009501794462   I S1            I 2017-06-18  I  NULL         I 23.000000
000009999203079   I S1            I 2017-06-18  I  NULL         I 23.000000
000009995553079   I S1            I 2017-06-18  I  NULL         I 23.000000
```

I presume the issue is with the count not counting NULL

Comment: What does the `Removaldate` mean? Is it the date where the old version of the record in the database table is "removed", making place for a new record with updated values and `Removaldate` being NULL? Or is it the date on which the meter is actually physically removed?

Comment: Physically removed, the piece I'm looking at is how old the metering portfolio is.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Because now I do not understand the logic behind your data. You can have a meter (serial number 000009501794462) being both installed and removed at the same time (after 2018-01-22)? Shouldn't the record with `Removaldate` NULL have a `InstallDate` value >= 2018-01-22?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, I think you just need to remove [Removaldate] from the GROUP BY, get rid of the HAVING and use MIN([Removaldate]) in the calculation of Age_M and the ORDER BY like this:

```
SELECT  
    [MeterSerialNumber]
    ,[EquipmentType]
    ,[InstallDate]
    ,MIN([Removaldate]) as REM_DATE
    ,ROUND(DATEDIFF(DAY, InstallDate, case when MIN(Removaldate) IS null then CONVERT (date,GETDATE()) else MIN(Removaldate) end)/30.42,0) as Age_M
FROM 
    Tbl_Device_ISU
WHERE 
    EquipmentType in ('S1','NS','NSS') or EquipmentType like ('%S2%')
GROUP BY 
    MeterSerialNumber,
    EquipmentType,
    InstallDate
ORDER BY 
    MeterSerialNumber,
    REM_DATE desc
```